# Qt OpenGL (QOpenGLWidget) - Simple Triangle

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es

As a newbee to QT+OpenGL using QOpenGLWidget, I am unable to color my triangle.
Please find my code here, using QMainWindow for GUI ...

```
// main.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Here the GUI - window

```
// MainWindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Here implementation - file ...

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Here is the widget rendering Opengl-Context.

```
#ifndef OPENGLWIDGET_H
#define OPENGLWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLContext>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QOpenGLVertexArrayObject>
#include <QMatrix4x4>

class OpenglWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, public QOpenGLFunctions
{
public:
    OpenglWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~OpenglWidget();

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);
    void paintGL();
    GLuint m_posAttr;
    GLuint m_colAttr;
    GLuint m_matrixUniform;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram *m_program;
};
#endif // OPENGLWIDGET_H
```

Here is the implementation file ...

```
#include "openglwidget.h"


OpenglWidget::OpenglWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    setFormat(QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat());
}

OpenglWidget::~OpenglWidget()
{
}

static const char *vertexShaderSource =
    "attribute highp vec4 posAttr;\n"
    "attribute lowp vec4 colAttr;\n"
    "varying lowp vec4 col;\n"
    "uniform highp mat4 matrix;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   col = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);\n"
    "   gl_Position = matrix * posAttr;\n"
    "}\n";

static const char *fragmentShaderSource =
    "varying lowp vec4 col;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   gl_FragColor = col;\n"
    "}\n";

void OpenglWidget::initializeGL()
{
    makeCurrent();
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Create Shader (Do not release until VAO is created)
    m_program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram(this);
    m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vertexShaderSource);
    m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, fragmentShaderSource);
    m_program->link();
    m_posAttr = m_program->attributeLocation("posAttr");
    m_colAttr = m_program->attributeLocation("colAttr");
    m_matrixUniform = m_program->attributeLocation("matrix");

    m_program->release();
}

void OpenglWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    makeCurrent();

    //m_program->bind();

    QMatrix4x4 matrix;
    matrix.perspective(60.0f, 4.0f/3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    matrix.translate(0, 0, -2);

    m_program->setUniformValue(m_matrixUniform, matrix);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        0.0f, 0.707f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    GLfloat colors[] = {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    glVertexAttribPointer(m_posAttr, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(m_colAttr, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    m_program->release();
}

void OpenglWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Here the rendered triangle is just white.
I am unable to understand whether the shader is compiled and attributes are linked but still, I am unable to color the triangle.

If I can get any guidance... ???[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4nLu.jpg)

Comment: Check for success of your shader compilations. These shaders will not compile with a compliant OpenGL implementation. Precision qualifiers are not supported in GLSL 1.10, which is what you're using if you don't specify a shader version.

Comment: I checked, the return flag of **addShaderFromSourceCode** is it's saying true.

Comment: You're fortunate then, in the sense that the OpenGL implementation does not detect the error. It could well fail on another platform. Another problem is that you're using the result of `attributeLocation()` for the attribute locations in some places, but hardwired values in others, like the `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at what your shaders do. Your fragment shader:

> ```
> varying lowp vec4 col;
> [...]
>    gl_FragColor = col;
> ```

So it will take the `col` output of each vertex, interpolated for each fragment in the primitive, and use that as the final color.

Now your vertex shader:

> ```
>    col = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
> ```

That's clearly **red**.  The fact that you added some `colAttr` input attribute, and specify some vertex array for that, is totally irrelevant as long as you don't actually use that attribute - currently, it is an inactive attribute that is just optimized out, as it never influences any output.

**UPDATE**

If you get a white triangle, this indicated that your shaders aren't even used at all. There is a `mprogram->release()` call in your `paintGL` method, but you never actually *enable* the program, so it won't be used.

Comment: `(1, 0, 0, 1)` is red, not white.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: omg, I didn't even notice that. There must be something else wrong, then.

Comment: @derhass:

Hii !

I am thankful for your kind reply. I noticed your 2 points

Point-1: (While testing the ColAttr - I maid it hard-coded to red color.), if compiler optimizing it for the "colAttr". The triangle at-least come red.

Point-2: As I believe you are point to :

//m_program->bind();
m_program->bind();

If I am uncomment it (as the definition: equivalent to calling glUseProgram().) the triangle didn't render.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use

```
m_colAttr = m_program->attributeLocation("col");
```

instead of

```
m_colAttr = m_program->attributeLocation("colAttr");
```

If you write in shader

```
gl_FragColor = col;
```

**col = col, colAttr != col**

Change name of attribute, and if this doesn't help change this call in initializeGL

```
program->release();
```

to

```
program->bind();
```